# Call of a router with registration module in gatsby.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, backend

Hi I have a frontend application written in gatsby.js and a backend in node.js that uses rest express.js for bees, I have to make a rest call from a gatsby.js form to an express.js router passing the values ​​of the form. To do this I use the codes below but they don't seem to work

**Frotend Gatsby.js:**

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "gatsby";
import server from "../setup.js";
import Layout from "../components/layout";
import SEO from "../components/seo";

//Variabile che rappresenta il router per la registrazione al server
var loginaddress=server.server+"/login";

//Pagina di registrazione
const NuovoPage = () => (
  <Layout>
    <SEO title="Registrazione" />

    <form method="POST" action={loginaddress}>
    Email:    <input type="text"  name="Email" /> <p></p>
    Password: <input type="password"  name="Password" /> <p></p>
   <br></br>
    <input type="button" value="Registrazione" />
    <p></p>
    </form>
    <Link to="/">Ritorna alla homepage</Link>
  </Layout>
)

//Esporto la pagina della pagina di registrazione
export default NuovoPage
```

**Package.json of Frontend:**

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8787",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "gatsby": "^2.18.12",
    "gatsby-image": "^2.2.34",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^2.2.31",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^3.0.27",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^3.1.16",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^2.3.5",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^2.1.40",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^2.3.7",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.16",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-helmet": "^5.2.1"
  },
```

**Backend Gatsby.js**

```
//Esegue la registrazione  dell'utente
app.post("/login", async function (request, response) {

    console.log("Chiamata al router /registrazione in GET");

});
```

Comment: Both are running in two different ports isn't in local ?

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS 
exactly the front runs on the 8080 and the backend on the 8787

Comment: so you should connect it isn't, so if you are using package.json you can add the proxy so basically if your client runs in localhost:8080/registrazione, when it starts requesting it should proxy to localhost:8787/registrazione then only your back end will catch it, so adding proxy will solve it, you can add like this in package.json , "proxy": "http://localhost:8787". Try this and when you update package.json you need to restart it okay !!

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS
I added the proxy but still does not make the rest call

Comment: is the call is going to the back end put a console.log('here') in your router and check in your express.js

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS 
I checked

frontend call http://localhost: 8787 / login

backend: it is running on port 8787 does not receive the call


I added "proxy": "http: // localhost: 8787", on package.json

Comment: front end port is 8080 isn't

Comment: Backend:  is running on port 8787 , Frontend: is running on port 8080

Comment: So in the client package.json only you have added the proxy isn't

Comment: In frontend package.json i have add port-proxy of backend.

Comment: Can you add the package.json in the question

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS i have add it

Comment: try hitting localhost:8787/login check your console.log('here') is comming

Comment: I tried but nothing changes, using postman the call arrives at the router on a local backend, so the problem lies with the frontend that is not making the rest call @DILEEPTHOMAS

Comment: try hitting the localhost:8787/login from your browser, and check whether in the terminal console.log() happened

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS  localhost:8787/login from your browser

Comment: yes hit that url from your chrome browser ? and check in the terminal are you getting the log